# How to find class from inside pseudo class

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to find a class from inside the pseudo class to change property depend on which class it has (default or invert).

**LESS**

```
.callout {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    &.default {
        background: #f0f0f0;
        color: #333333;
    }
    &.invert {
        background: #333333;
        color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    &.right {
        float: right;
        &:after {
            right: 100%;
            top: 30px;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border-width: 19px 19px 0px 30px;
            margin-top: -20px;

            //This is working now but can I change border-right-color depend on which class it has, default or invert.
            border-right-color: red;

            //This is the area I am struggling...
            .default & {
                border-right-color: #f0f0f0;
            }
            .invert & {
                border-right-color: #333333;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="callout invert right">This is callout text... </div>
```

**JS Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/kunjsharma/La68gnx7/2/

Comment: `.invert& {border-right-color: #333333}`.

Comment: Hi @seven-phases-max , thanks for reply. `.invert&` probably not a correct syntax for less. Can you explain/fiddle your reply?

Comment: Don't guess. Just write and go further.

Comment: Tried, not working :(

Comment: *Tried, not working* Dude, please realize that your fiddle code is SCSS. So are your asking about Less or Sass? They are two different languages.

Comment: Actually fiddle don't have LESS option to choose but it works fine as expected.

Comment: It "works" only until your code is simple down to the point when both languages are mostly a CSS yet. Now listen to yourself, you're trying to compile Less code (suggested by a guy with a 10K+ rep in *Less* tag) with an SCSS compiler and complain it's not working. :) Is it a joke?

Comment: I caught the issue: mistake when implement demo code on my system inside head section of page. When I link it with `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />` its working fine. Thank you very much for all your efforts.

Comment: Here's [codepen](https://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/wbeEXG) and here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seven_phases_max/do80mbvz) (with Less compiler enabled).
And you should really revise your learning workflow: 1. Never guess 1. Read [the manuals](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) 3. Use proper tools (something "working" accidentally stops to work at any moment and you never know if it's your mistake or just the wrong whole).

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max for efforts and saying, it means a lot for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @seven-phases-max , here is your pen code. And the solution is: when space removed from `.class` and `&` (e.g.: `.invert&`), it works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="callout right">I am just .right</div>
<div class="callout right default">I am also .default</div>
<div class="callout right invert">And I am .invert</div>
```

**LESS**

```
.callout {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px;
    &.default {
        background: #f0f0f0;
        color: #333333;
    }
    &.invert {
        background: #333333;
        color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    &.right {
        float: right;
        &:after {
            right: 100%;
            top: 30px;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border-width: 19px 19px 0px 30px;
            margin-top: -20px;

            border-right-color: red;

            .default& {
                border-right-color: green;
            }
            .invert& {
                border-right-color: blue;
            }

        }

    }
}
```